# How to create restful api in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

How to create restful api in rails?

```
gem 'rails-api'
```

if i use rails-api gem is it create a restfull api? if no which gem should I use to create restful api?

Answer (score 0):

Grape gem is excellent for building REST Api's! See the link:
https://github.com/intridea/grape